# What device like Arduino/Raspberry Pi support Windows software such as setup.exe?

Tags: arduino, hardware

I am trying to run a software that came with a `Alphasense NDIR CO2 sensor` on small device like `Raspberry Pi` and `Arduino`. I can't run `.exe` files on them so I am seeking help on what small device will do the trick.

I can only get data out through the software it came with which requires a PC. It does not work like other sensor that I can just wire it to `Arduino` and get data out and saved on a SD card without a PC. So, I assume a code is needed to be send to be able to log the data which was built-in on the software. So I am trying to run the software on a small device since I do not know the code for logging data.

Comment: You could try WINE on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: wine only provides system libraries, it doesn't emulate a different architecture.

Comment: Google for "arduino x86" or "raspberry pi x86", there are plenty devices nowadays that are similar to the arduino but use an x86 compatible cpu. Most of them won't be able to run windows though, so if you need that for your .exe you'll most probably end up using an [intel compute stick](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/compute-stick/intel-compute-stick.html) or something very similar.

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry Pi in its version 2 supports `Windows 10 IoT Core`, not a full version of `Windows` but could you start here. [MORE INFO](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/iot)

Comment: it's still ARM though.

Comment: There is no need to mention it. Windows .exe files are nearly always compiled for the x86 architecture. So you need either a system using an x86 or compatible CPU or an alternative architecture with enough computing power to run an emulator (which doesn't fit with the arduino/pi requirements). That basically rules out every system that doesn't use an x86 cpu.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm developer and "...are nearly always..." is a bad expression when you are talking about computer science because if someone doesn't mentioned a detail, I couldn't suppose it. Tons of time have been lost because of this expression.